# Create a valid regex for validating name

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate name in my `react native` application and I need 
`regex` for validating names

Valid names: Dr. John
             St. Peter's 
Invalid names: Dr.. John
               St.. Peters''s'.

Two special characters should not come side by side and only ' and . is allowed . Also name should not start with these special characters but can end with a . not with '

Below is the `regex` I am using but it takes any no of ' and . side by side

```
/[!0-9@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,<>\/?]/
```

Comment: do you want to include the spaces between names??

Comment: yes space is valid

Comment: are these the names of businesses? for exmaple, is, say, `Joey's` potential input and or valid output? please be more specific as to what exactly can be input and what valid output is

Comment: No these are person names but we want to include ' and . in validations

Comment: Name validation? https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific about the input and output...

Comment: `St.` and `Dr.` are not part of a name, it is a *title*.

Answer (score 0):

`[a-zA-Z]+\.?\s?'?(?!$)` Should do the trick. It works fine in JavaScript.

I haven't spent much time making it as efficient as possible, so there might be better ways to accomplish this.

Good luck.

**[ EDIT ]**

This should work for the most part: `[a-zA-Z ]+(\.|')?[a-zA-Z ]+(\.|')?`

This is what I'm testing against:
`Dr. John St. Pet .er's` matches: `Dr. John St.` and `Pet .er'`
`Dr.'. John St.. Peter''s'` matches: `Dr.` and `John St.` and `Peter'`
`Anthony` matches: `Anthony`
`Timbo J. Fadds` matches: `Timbo J. Fadds`
`Sally Esquire` matches: `Sally Esquire`

It only really messes up when testing against strings with lots of "illegal" characters.

Anyways, I'm not going to invest any more time into this until you clarify exactly what the input can be and what the output needs to be.

**[ EDIT ]**

`[^(\.|')|(\.|')]+(\.|')?` may work...

Comment: I will try and let you know if this works. Anyway thanks!

Comment: @ParasWatts NP! If it works, be sure to vote it up ;)

Comment: I tried and it is not working in case '. or '' or .. are used side by side which should not be allowed

Comment: why would `'.` ever be used side-by-side in a name?? also, that should have been included in your question, so people like myself don't waste our time on solutions that don't solve problems...

Comment: Two special characters should not come side by side this I have clearly written you can check

Comment: @ParasWatts ohhh, i thought u said it was doing that. my bad

Comment: @ParasWatts i need to know can a string start with a ` `, `.`, and or `'`, and can it end with either of those characters?

Comment: it can end with those characters but can not start, but it does not matter that much, I just want two special characters . and ' or .. or '' should not come together

Comment: @ParasWatts so how do you imagine dealing with input like `Dr.'. John St.. Peter''s'` what is valid, if anything, in that string? can an output end with `.` or `'`?

Comment: User will enter the name and if it valid then ok if not valid error will be shown, we are allowing ' and . besides alphabets and want .' or .. or '' .i.e two special characters  side by side should not be allowed

Comment: @ParasWatts so... `Dr.John St. Pet .er's` is a valid name in your system? lol AGAIN, you have to be more SPECIFIC

Comment: I have updated my question.I hope it will be more clear now

Comment: @ParasWatts your edit doesn't help. when i say be more specific, i mean make a list of ALL valid formats of input and ALL valid formats of output. if you can't do that, you have no idea what you're looking for............... i've edited my question nonetheless. now i'm seriously going to stop wasting my time with this until you provide the necessary information

Answer (score 0):

I advise try it and i hope be useful:

`([A-z])+(.?[a-zA-Z])*('?[a-zA-Z])*`

Answer (score 0):

The regex should look something like this:

`^(?!(.*(([^a-zA-Z\.\'\s])|(\.{2,})|('{2,}|\s{2,}))))`

You can fork and add more test cases here:

https://regexfiddler.com/e/0ptjxdnr7y5r/test-valid-name